# Earthing vs. grounding

Tags: electric-circuits, electricity, terminology, short-circuits

In some websites they say there is a difference between Earthing and grounding but some of them say they
don't. Is there any difference between "Earthing" and "grounding"?

Comment: Please give some specific examples.

Comment: Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/421876/ground-common-and-earth-ground-confusion

Answer (score 0):

The answer you want may be found [here](https://www.toppr.com/guides/physics/difference-between/earthing-and-grounding/)

---

**Simplified (alot):**

Earthing is connecting wires that aren't live to the Earth. This reduces chances of electric shocks from a faulty system and from lightning strikes.

Grounding is connecting a part of a live wire to the Earth. This inulates devices and protects the components.

Comment: I don't think so.   A "live" wire presumably is either the hot feed or the neutral return, neither of which you want tied to ground.  You missed the part about the neutral having a resistive connection to Earth.

Comment: The neutral return wire is tied to ground, @CarlWitthoft.  At least it is in the US power distribution systems - I doubt it's different other places that use AC distribution.

Comment: @Brick  but that tie point (neutral to ground) occurs in only one place, typically back of th breaker panel.  It's a code violation to connect ground wires to neutral anywhere else

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I agree with the last comment.  Neutral is grounded in a specific place, but your original comment made it sound categorically like it's not grounded at all.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the terms usually mean the same thing.

In European and other standards outside the US the term "earthing" is used, while in the US the term grounding is used, notably in the US National Electrical Code (NEC).

For example, in the NEC the conductor used to conductively connect the metal housings of electrical products to earth is called the "equipment grounding conductor" whereas in IEC standards it's called the "protective earthing conductor".

In either case, the objective (protection against electric shock) is the same: make a conductive connection to the Earth either directly, or indirectly by connection to something having a conductive path the earth (e.g., metal plumbing in the US). It's possible the term "earthing" may be used to refer to the former and "grounding" to the latter.

Hope this helps

Comment: If you've been to DESY when the positron beam is on (non superconducting magnetics), the loud speaker plays a female voice: "Da Magnite ist nich geerde.....The Magnetic is not shorted to Earth" constantly every minute or so. Not sure what they meant...grounded, perhaps? Obviously touching a 1 km raw copper wire carrying thousands of amps is indeed, verboten.

Comment: @JEB Sorry, never been to DESY. Have no idea what "the Magnetic" is and what electrical hazards are involved with the "magnetic" if it is not grounded.  But the main purpose of grounding is to keep accessible metal parts at or close to ground (zero) potential, in case a fault occurs between hazardous live parts and those accessible metal parts. The idea is to reduce the risk of electric shock.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the following usage:
"earth ground" or "earthing" is a path which terminates (conductively) in the actual ground.

Just plain 'ground' can refer to a ground plane in a box full of electronics.  This ground plane is common to all the electronics but is not necessarily tied to an external earth ground, especially if the hot and neutral voltage lines are floating (via transformer power feed).

Answer (score 0):

**Earthing** is mostly used to prevent electric shocks. When the electrical system overloads, grounding is usually employed to unbalance it. Earthing is positioned between the equipment body and the underground pit, beneath the earth pit. It is situated between the equipment's neutral and the ground.

1)**Earthing:**
Earthing protects humans from electric shock.

**Grounding:**
Grounding keeps the entire electrical power system from failing.

2)**Earthing:**
The earth utilised is green in colour.

**Grounding:**
The grounding wire is black in colour.

3)**Earthing:**
It is used to prevent life-threatening shocks.

**Grounding:**
It is used to balance the electric overloads induced by voltage fluctuations.

4)**Earthing:**
Earthing is done between the Earth and the electrical device or equipment.

**Grounding:**
It connects the ground to the equipment's utilised neutral.

5)**Earthing:**
It is a British term.

**Grounding:**
It is a phrase from the United States.

6)**Earthing:**
As the earth (neutral earth) is an equipotential surface, a circuit is connected to it.

**Grounding:**
A circuit is not physically connected to the earth, but its potential is zero with regard to it.
[image: Electrical system without Earthing]
Visit for more: https://dewwool.com/difference-between-earthing-and-grounding/

Answer (score 0):

Here’s my best guess based on reading about this stuff a lot as well as some introduction about electrical safety information. Disclaimer: I am not a trained electrician. I am a physicist who has spent some time thinking about "ground". Working with electricity can be dangerous and even fatal.

Note that in this post I give particular definitions for "grounding" and "earthing". These are the definitions that I think make the most cohesive sense given my research on the subject. However, there's a good chance that my definitions are not consistent with definition's you will find out in the wild. That's because, frankly, out in the wild, the definitions are all over the place and sometimes straight up do not make sense.

## Table of Contents:

- Introduction
- Dangerous naive wiring
- Safer wiring with an Equipment Grounding Conductor (EGC)
- Grounding
- Earthing
- Other uses of the term "ground"
- Aside on lifted/bootleg ground

## Introduction

Let’s focus on ac systems.

First you need to understand that only two wires are needed (in a physics sense) to drive electrical devices. You just need to provide a voltage difference at the power terminals of the device.

Why then, in the US and other parts of the world, do electrical outlets expose 3 conductors at outlets? The answer is for the safety of humans in the case of certain types of electrical faults. I’ll refer to the third prong as the equipment ground conductor (EGC). It is the round prong on US outlets and plugs. What types of faults does this conductor guard against and how? First off, this conductor does not guard against faults on its own. It relies on details of how the different conductor wires are wired up within a building, at the service panel AND relies on a functioning circuit breaker. If any of these elements is missing or incorrect then the EGC does not provide the safety mechanism it is meant to provide.

So how does EGC provide protection?

## Dangerous Naive Wiring

Diagram #1:

[image]

Imagine we’re in a super outdated building with two prongs A and B to provide electricity. Imagine we have a metal microwave and a metal toaster and we plug both of these into the building at two outlets. Imagine that typically the metal cases of the two appliances are electrically insulated from the A and B electrical lines. Now imagine A shorts to the metal chassis of the microwave (i.e. an electrical connection is formed between A and the metal case of the microwave, perhaps a stray piece of metal lodges between A and the case somehow or a wire frays and touches the case). In this case the microwave will still operate fine. Suppose also B shorts to the metal chassis of the toaster. Again the toaster will still operate fine. But now there is a large voltage difference between the microwave and toaster. Now imagine a human touches the case of the microwave with one hand and the case of the toaster with their other hand. At US voltage levels the voltage difference between the human's hands could provide lethal currents from one hand to the other, through the human's heart. So in this case, these two faults can create a fatal situation.

## Safer Wiring with an Equipment Grounding Conductor (EGC)

How does the EGC prevent this type of fatal situation? Let's focus on the toaster in a wiring system including EGC:

[image]

We see a few differences. First, in the previous circuit A and B were basically symmetric so we just named them A and B. But now the two power carrying wires have different wirings so we give them different asymmetric names, Hot and Neutral. Second, there is a circuit breaker on the hot line. This may trip at, e.g. 10 amps. Third, there is a third conductor called the EGC which is electrically connected to neutral at the power source (the service panel) and which is connected to the metal chassis of the toaster. The first consequence of this is that the metal chassis is now at the same voltage as the neutral wire. Under normal operation, this would mean that both the toaster and microwave chasses would be at the same potential, namely that of the neutral wire. This means if a human touches both of them at once there is no risk of shock. But what about in the event of a fault? Suppose the Hot wire shorts to the chassis of the toaster. Well in this case there would be a complete circuit for current to flow from the source, through the circuit breaker, along the hot wire, through the fault onto the chassis, then on the EGC wire and back to the source. If the fault is low resistance then a very high current flow tripping the circuit breaker. THIS IS THE PURPOSE OF CIRCUIT BREAKERS! when a fault a occurs the circuit breaker trips. If someone tries to reset the circuit breaker without fixing the fault the breaker will just immediately trip again. It makes it so nothing can operate while the fault is present. It is not possible to get into a situation where the chassis of any box is "Hot". Note that under normal operating circumstances the EGC never carries current but Hot and Neutral do.

In typically wired buildings, all electronic appliances have their chasses connected to EGCs. Furthermore other exposed metal like metal plumbing lines are connected to EGCs as well. This ensures that any exposed metal surface is protected from becoming "Hot" by the EGC + circuit breaker.

## Grounding

As far as I can tell, when it comes to building wiring, the entire above discussion is what is commonly meant by **GROUNDING**. Specifically, grounding is the inclusion of a third conductor in addition to hot and neutral which is (1) bonded to neutral at the service panel (see section below on lifted/bootleg ground) and (2) bonded to the exposed metal surfaces (such as appliance chasses and plumbing) in an electrically wired building. Note that under this definition grounding does little to nothing to increase safety in the absence of functioning circuit breakers.

Note that at no point in this discussion of "grounding" have I made reference to the Earth or the connection of any conductors to Earth e.g. by driving a metal rod into the ground and connecting electrical conductors to that rod. The EGC has absolutely nothing to do with Earth and, in fact, EGCs can be found on airplanes or boats that have no way to connect to a metal rod driven into the earth.

## Earthing

As far as I can tell, **EARTHING** is the practice of driving a metal rod into the dirt and connecting the EGC of a building (or any structure with electricity such as a telephone pole) to that metal rod. This is meant to ensure that no large voltage can be established between an electrical system and the earth. Such a potential difference would lead to arcs or shocks if not eliminated. I am less of an expert in earthing. The mechanisms for buildup of potential difference between a body and the earth are a little more mysterious to me so it's harder to see why this needs to be mitigated. One important case is that of lightning. Suppose a structure is struck by lightning. This may result in a large charge build up on the structure that would lead to a potential difference between the structure and the earth. The grounding rod will dissipate this excess charge and equalize the voltage between the structure and Earth. Airplanes are actually another important example. Suppose an airplane builds up charge while it is flying (perhaps due to motion of particles and ionization). I understand that accidents have occurred when the plane lands and tries to refuel. There is a spark between the fuel pump and the airplane that can ignite the gas. In this case you'd want to earth the airplane somehow before fueling. Airplanes also have so-called [static dischargers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_discharger) to help them dissipate excess charge.

So in short, "earthing" is the practice of making a conductive connection between some body and the earth itself. It's purpose is also for electrical safety but the reasons are very different than that of what I have called grounding above.

Note that people VERY REGULARLY misunderstand earthing and grounding and think, for example, that the physical connection to the earth is necessary for the EGC to provide safety. Often these misunderstanding will be coupled with something about needing a common reference point for different parts of the system and a misunderstanding of how current flows in a complete circuit. You'll find this stuff all over the internet and perhaps in other answers to this question.

## Other uses of "grounding"

So far I've focused primarily on the "grounding" having to do with the EGC and shock prevention as well as "earthing" having to do with preventing static charge buildup. There are other uses of the term ground.

Putting electrical safety aside, it is common to hear certain conductors or planes on printed circuit boards or other types of electrical circuits to be referred to as ground. Think about a radio receiver or transmitter or laboratory electronics boxes. These all have PCBs in them. In these cases the power terminal at lower voltage (and connected conductive elements) will be referred to as ground. In lab, testing, or audio recording/playback settings There are important considerations with how ground conductors between various electrical boxes are wired up pertaining to signal integrity. That is, if you do things wrong you can pickup excess noise. This is related to the concept of ground loops. I won't go into more detail here. I'm just pointing out that all of these things are also called ground and again, all of this has nothing to do with a conductor driven into the actual Earth. These usages of "ground" are unrelated to electrical safety and a more pertinent to signal integrity. However, the safety requirement to connect chasses to the EGC is sometimes an important consideration when it comes to designing sensitive "signal ground" systems.

Finally, in all of what I have discussed above there was never really current flowing into, out of, or through the earth except for perhaps minor transient static discharge currents (or during lightning strikes). Apparently, there are a minority of power transmission systems which transmit power over land with a single wire carrying current above ground and then using current flowing through the earth itself as the return. These are called [single-wire earth return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-wire_earth_return) (SWER) power transmission systems. Note that most power transmission systems do not operate this way. Typically there are at least two or more conductors above or in the earth that carry current (and in fact act as waveguides for AC electromagnetic fields) to transmit power over land. But in a discussion of grounding it's worth bringing up these SWER systems.

## Dangerous Practice of Lifted or Bootleg Ground

*In some older wired buildings with 2 prong outlets (i.e. no EGC) you may see something called a lifted ground or bootleg ground where (respectively) either the EGC prong of a modern appliance or the EGC prong of a modern outlet is bonded to the neutral wire at the outlet. Note in this case there are just two wires (what used to be called A and B) running from the panel to the outlet. The lifted or bootleg ground is a dangerous workaround to the problem that there are two wires in the wall, but three prongs on the modern appliance. This is a very dangerous practice because if the neutral wire becomes severed somewhere inside the wall the chassis of the appliance will now become Hot. Short of rewiring the building to include EGC, the proper safety measure here is to replace the outlet with a GFCI outlet. This device measures current flowing in on hot and out on neutral and if there is a difference, it assumes that the current is returning through some alternative path (like maybe a human connected to some other metal object which is connected to the service panel through some path) and trips a "breaker" inside the outlet. Note that the chassis becoming hot is less of a risk in a system with EGC because at the very least you would need both the Neutral and EGC conductors to be severed in the wall and you would also need a short between either Neutral or Hot and the chassis.